# Why do I keep getting an 'object of type method has no len()' error when using Django's pagination?

Tags: django, pagination

Been trying to figure out why do I keep getting *"object of type 'method' has no len()", where it directs me to this line. Please help I've been at it for the past 3 days and i really want to pull my hair out.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def index(request):
    allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse

    #paginator
    paginator = Paginator(allPosts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    *posts_of_page = paginator.get_page(page_number)*

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "allPosts" : allPosts,
        "posts_of_page" :  posts_of_page,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add "()" at the env of your

```
allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse
```

so allPosts is reverse method instead of QuerySet

to fix your issue you should modify this line to look like this:

```
allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse()
```

Comment: wow you're actually a saviour

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted answer